# How to read client certificate in polarssl?

Tags: ssl, tls1.2, mbed, polarssl

How to *read client certificate from server side* using `mbedtls(polarssl)`?
I had a server that was coded using `mbedtls(polarssl)`. I want to read the client certificate and fetch some information from that certificate. Can anyone know *what function* will be used to read client certificate?

Comment: Have you taken a look at example programs at https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbedtls/tree/development/programs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could use [mbedtls_x509_crt_info](https://tls.mbed.org/api/group__x509__module.html#gabaf30f2269fc3b6608b25871f9d09da6) which returns an informational string about the certificate.

You can `get the peer certificate from the ssl session` when the client connects and then print the info out.

```
mbedtls_ssl_context ssl;

...

mbedtls_x509_crt *crt = ssl.session->peer_cert;

unsigned char buf[1024];
int ret = mbedtls_x509_crt_info((char *) buf, sizeof( buf ) - 1, "", crt);
if( ret != -1 )
{
    mbedtls_printf( "%s\n", buf );
}
```

I didn't test this, just checked the examples.